# Counting number of RSI "peaks" while RSI level > 70

Tags: pine-script

I would like to count the number "peaks" an RSI line makes WHILE the RSI remains above 70, and then plot a shape once 5 of them occur (ie, 5 occur before dropping down below 70).

A peak for now is just defined as the RSI rising since the last bar.

Eg in this example, the count would be 3 (not enough to trigger a shape being plotted, but just to be clear).

[image]

Once the level drops below 70, the count would stop/reset; ie the next time a peak happens above RSI level of 70 will be "1".

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
rsiPeaksOver70 = 0
myResult = for i = 1 to 5 by 1
    if rsi <= 70 and rsi[1] >= rsi
        break
    rsiPeaksOver70 := rsiPeaksOver70 + i

plotshape(rsiPeaksOver70, style=shape.xcross, size=size.normal, location=location.bottom)
```

And here is the result...

[image]

If I try plotting as columns I get a similar result (also it's not actually incrementing; the columns stay the same size).

Current Issues:

1. For some reason it will only respect one condition at a time! Either criteria works independently, but when I add an `and` it drops the <= 70... Not sure what is happening there.
2. I don't know how to only plot the shape if the count reaches 5. I tried "returning" the result at the bottom of the loop and adding a `rsiPeaksOver70 = 5` to the plotshape series parameter, but that failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script that counts RSI peaks and draws a cross once target number is counted. Counter is reset when RSI drops below the level.

I used RSI level 60 and peak count 3 so its easier to get desired peak count.

```
//@version=4
study("RSI peak count")

_rsiPeaks = 0
_overboughtLevel = input(title="RSI Level", type=input.float, defval=60, minval=0, maxval=100)
_rsiPeriod = input(title="RSI Period", type=input.integer, defval=6, minval=1)
_targetPeaks = input(title="Peaks to count until signal", type=input.integer, defval=3, minval=1, maxval=100)
_rsi = rsi(close, _rsiPeriod)

hline(_overboughtLevel, title='Overbought', color=color.blue, linestyle=hline.style_dotted)

_rsiPeaks := _rsiPeaks[1]
if(_rsi[1]<_overboughtLevel)
    _rsiPeaks := 0 // reset counter if we visited under overbought level

_peak = false
if(_rsi[1]>_overboughtLevel and _rsi[1]>_rsi and _rsi[1]>_rsi[2])
    _rsiPeaks := _rsiPeaks + 1 // previous rsi value was a peak
    _peak := true


plotshape(_peak and _rsiPeaks == _targetPeaks ? _rsi : na, offset =-1, style=shape.xcross, color=color.fuchsia, size=size.small, location=location.bottom)
plot(_rsi)
```

Comment: Cool! It's sort of like a loop... without a loop. Thank you this was so elusive for me.